# How to get all the alocation done to the heap with C language(garbage collector)

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory

I want to build my own garbage collector with the C language. Studies some algorithms for it and come across the mark-sweep algorithm. But to implement it I need to get all the allocation that has been done by the program. I don't know any way of doing it so if you could help me with it I would be more than happy.

By the way, this project is only for educational purposes so I am aware that I won't work like production-ready ones on the market.

Comment: Roll your own `malloc` (or `new`).  That function can then keep track.

Comment: Also, C or C++?  There's a big difference, please tag only one.

Comment: Read about [Boehm garbage collector -  for C and C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector)  Source is available.

Comment: @PaulSanders *Also, C or C++? There's a big difference*  Probably not.  Almost every C++ implementation uses standard C `malloc()`/`free()`/etc under the hood for the explicit purpose of allowing the dynamic memory allocation mechanism to be replaced in its entirety with another.  That's how tools such as Valgrind work.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a program that uses your own `malloc`, `free`, `calloc`, `realloc`, and `alignedalloc` instead of the ones provided with your C implementation? For learning purposes, you can usually do that simply by writing your own function definitions, the same way you write other functions, and linking them into your program as usual. However, those routines will need a source of memory, such as a very large static array (for initial learning purposes) or a way to ask the operating system for memory (which requires learning about the operating system routines for that).

Comment: Which OS?  If you are using Linux you can make use of the [LD_PRELOAD trick](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ld_preload-trick-what-is) to 'install' your own functions but have them defer to the standard implementations for the actual work.

Comment: Which is basically how valgrind works.

Comment: Make your own `wrapper_malloc` and store all the allocations.

Comment: If you think that you need garbage collection in C then I suspect that we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.